# Call Windows DLL from Elixir/Erlang

Tags: dll, elixir

I use a `CAN` communication driver DLL for windows, which I call/import from C++, and I was wondering if there was a way to wrap the DLL and call it directly from Elixir, or maybe Erlang.

Comment: NIF is the keyword you're looking for - Native Implemented Functions

Comment: You may want to check out Rustler [https://github.com/rusterlium/rustler].